# How to ignore SSL errors in Qt5 QML QWebKit 3.0?

Tags: facebook, ssl, qml, qt5, qwebkit

I've got a problem showing **www.facebook.com** in `Qt5 QML QWebKit 3.0`.

The problem is with *SSL certificate*. There is a solution for `Qt 4.*`, but I need to implement this in the `Qt 5.0.1` where all the API had changed.

The example solution for `Qt 4.*` could be found here [link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8911)

Comment: Are you sure about "all the API had changed" part? Most of the API just got renamed when going to QML1 to QML2. For instance, you have QQmlNetworkAccessManagerFactory and the QQmlEngine::setNetworkAccessManagerFactory method. Whether the QNetworkAccessManager used there gets picked up and used by WebKit, is another story.

Comment: Yes, I'm. Anyway I've found the solution. I tried the solution, you talking about - it didn't help me. Another way - to use ignoreSSLError couldn't be used in new QWebKit 3.0 due to important changes in QML WebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, how you could ignore SSL errors from QML in Qt5. It helped me to show facebook page. I'm to use experimental API. The solution is correct for Qt 5.0.1 msvc2010 version in Windows 7 64bit.

```
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0

WebView {
    id: webView;
    url: "https://www.facebook.com";
    experimental.certificateVerificationDialog: Item {
        Component.onCompleted: {
            model.accept();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve this problem with Qt 5.1 and MinGW4.8 using the experimental feature.

Finally I installed the new Qt 5.2 release that has a more expressive error message:

```
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

So with this new information the solution was installing Win32OpenSSL: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: I was having similar warnings, The reason was that the SSL version on my computer was outdated but when I updated it all those warnings were gone.